# How to remove padding on top of NavigationView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm wondering how to remove the top padding just above the NavigationView in SwiftUI.

Here's the problem:
[image: Xcode 1]

Code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    
    var deeds: [Deed] = deedsData
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(deeds) { item in
                Image(systemName: "doc.fill")
                
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("title"))
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView(deeds: deedsData)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the appearance of the `large` navigation bar.

You can use the `inline` style instead:

```
List(deeds) { item in
    Image(systemName: "doc.fill")
    
}
.navigationTitle(Text("title"))
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // change style
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, but that was not the thing I was looking for. I want to completely remove the padding above NavigationView, I don’t want it to be inline.

Comment: @szakes1 This is not the *padding*, this is the part of the `NavigationView` itself.

Comment: So, is there any way I can do to remove that?

Comment: Do you have a `NavigationView` in your `ContentView` as well? If so you'll be stacking NavigationView's and that will add additional "padding". You should only have a NavigationView at the root level of your app. ie the ContentView.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `NavigationView` from `HomeView`, there seems one already present in parent view (and it is enough to construct navigation stack)

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    var deeds: [Deed] = deedsData
    
    var body: some View {
        List(deeds) { item in
            Image(systemName: "doc.fill")
            
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text("title"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The space is intended. it makes room for the toolbar items.

however, you could go for negative padding like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            YourListView()
                .navigationTitle("Title")
        }.padding(.top, -50)
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this simple solution. It allows me to have an .inline navigation title while also getting rid of the excess white spaces.

Comment: This indeed works, but bear in mind that you won't be able to handle any clicks/taps in the area in which the items with a negativ top padding are pushed into (tested in iOS 16.0).